# Why do I get an error after closing my GDX game window?

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

I created a new GDX project, added all the necessary configs so that it runs the way it should be. The problem, however, is that whenever I close the game window, it displays the following error:

`Execution failed for task ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()'.> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1`

Is it something I should be worried about? And if so, what should I change in my project/configs?

You can see the screenshot of my config file below:

[image: This is the config file, for the context]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing to worry about.

You can get rid of it by applying this config:

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
...

config.forceExit = false;
```

More details: https://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13209